# Redirecting C++ printf to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I currently have the following setup:

- Application (executable)
- C++ DLL (contains logic used by the executable and loads the C# DLL, temporarily has a console window for debugging)
- C# DLL (contains GUI)

The C# DLL uses a nuget package called [UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports/) in order to provide functions to C++. The method `ShowGui()` is provided by C#.
The C# DLL is loaded using `LoadLibrary()` and the `ShowGui()` method works correctly. However, I seem to have trouble understanding how I would go by implementing a function that allows C++ to send a message to C#.
Currently I came up with the following:

```
[DllExport("AddDebug")]
public static void AddDebug([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder s)
{
    guiMain.AddToTextbox(s.ToString()); // the GUI uses BeginInvoke to prevent cross-thread exceptions.
}
```

In C++ I have simply changed `printf()` to `AddDebug()` and this seems to work only half the time: at a certain point the C++ DLL gets blocked when trying to call AddDebug() and gets unresponsive.

I have used the following to debug in C++ (obviously calling `sendDebug` instead of `AddDebug`):

```
sendDebug(string s)
{
    cout << s;
    AddDebug(s);
    cout << s;
}
```

In the scenario of C++ blocking, the above code only displays the `string s` once and is never displayed by C#. Meaning `AddDebug()` is never completed.

I have tried looking for solutions but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. Changing to a complete C# solution is not an option as the C++ code is insanely large and would take too much time to "convert".

I hope my question is clear and that somebody maybe has a suggestion to keep me from pulling my hair out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just redirect `Console.Out` to something you can read? Like a `TextWriter`/`StringWriter`. You can also extend it to add events so you can safely display it on a UI. Seems a lot easier than messing with managed exports.

Comment: You know...there is an esoteric thing called **C++/CLI**, interop with between managed and unmanaged code (in both directions) is its primary _raison d'etre_. _Normal_ C++ code will compile smoothly and you can directly use .NET classes and assemblies (yes, there are few minor issues with _corner usages_ but there are good chances you won't see them).

Comment: There are a lot of possible failure modes here.  Hopefully you did not declare AddDebug() to take an std::string argument.  It is very easy to fire-hose the UI thread with code like this, diagnostic is that the thread is burning 100% core and no longer paints or responds to input.  Use OutputDebugString() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up implementing a [Named Pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). C# being the server and C++ being the client. Seems to work without any issues.